# Можно ли полагаться на sqrt при работе с целыми числами

Tags: c++, c, математика

В математике `x == sqrt(x * x)`

В C++ есть функция sqrt.
Если мы работает с целыми числами (int,long) можем ли мы быть уверенными, что

```
i == (int) sqrt(i * i)
```

Для всего положительного диапазона целых чисел таких, что `i * i <= MAX_INTEGER`?

Comment: Java и с++/с нельзя смешивать. Java работает по алгоритму виртуальной машины, которая должна обеспечить одинаковый результат вне зависимости от платформы. с++/с - позволяет создаёт код для процессора, и на одной птатформе может быть один результат, а на другой - другой результат. В общем виде считаю задачу неразрешимой.

Comment: Думаю, что вот так - можете: `i == (int) (sqrt(i * i)+0.5)`

Comment: В С++ sqrt для работы с целыми числами в стандартной библиотеке отсутствует. Если i - int, то выражение `i == (int) sqrt(i * i)` будет содержать аж 3 неопределенных поведения.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Стандарт арифметики с плавающей точкой [IEEE 754-2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) требует, чтобы результат следующих операций над числами с плавающей точкой:

- сложение,
- вычитание,
- умножение,
- деление,
- извлечение квадратного корня

был в точности таким, как если бы вычисления производились по следующему алгоритму:

1. Найти точный вещественный результат операции;
2. Округлить точный результат до числа с плавающей точкой в соответствии с требуемым режимом округления.

Стандарт определяет несколько режимов округления точного вещественного результата (в сторону положительной бесконечности, в сторону отрицательной бесконечности, в сторону нуля, а также до ближайшего числа с плавающей точкой), но все эти режимы объединяет одно — если точный вещественный результат представим числом с плавающей точкой точно, то при округлении он не изменится.

Таким образом, если у нас есть две целочисленные величины `f1` и `f2`, представленные типом с плавающей точкой , такие что в вещественных числах выполняется соотношение `f1 == sqrt(f2)`, то и при вычислениях с плавающей точкой указанное соотношение должно выполняться.

---

Все целые числа из отрезка `[-2**24; 2**24]` представимы точно числом с плавающей точкой одинарной точности [single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). В языках C/C++ обычно тип `float` как раз и предназначен для хранения чисел одинарной точности. В C++ есть [функции `std::sqrt()` и `std::sqrtf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) (в C только [`sqrtf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt)), принимающие/возвращающие значение типа `float`.

Если `f` — некоторое целое неотрицательное число типа `float` такое, что точный вещественный результат произведения `f * f` принадлежит отрезку `[0; 2**24]`, то равенство `f == std::sqrt(f * f)` должно быть истинно.

Если произведение `f * f` не принадлежит указанному выше отрезку, то оно просто напросто может быть не представимо точно типом `float`, следовательно извлекать квадратный корень мы будем не из точного квадрата `f`, а из некоторого приближенного значения. Понятно, что равенство не обязательно будет выполняться.

---

В языках C/C++ тип `double` обычно соответствует формату чисел с плавающей точкой двойной точности [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). И все приведённые выше рассуждения для типа `float` верны и для `double`. Только отрезок, все целые числа из которого представимы точно типом `double`, таков: `[-2**53; 2**53]`. В C++ есть перегрузка `std::sqrt()` для работы с типом `double`, в C для работы с типом `double` также используется `sqrt()`

---

```
some_integral_type i = ...;
i == (some_integral_type) sqrt(i * i);
```

Если `i` — неотрицательно, и произведение `i * i` представимо типом `some_integral_type` и принадлежит отрезку `[0; 2**53]`, то приведённое равенство выполняется.
В C функция `sqrt` принимает аргумент типа `double`.
В C++ есть перегрузки (или шаблонная версия) функции `sqrt` для всех целочисленных типов. Внутри она преобразует параметр целочисленного типа к типу `double`.

---

Стандарты языков C/C++ не требуют, чтобы типы `float` и `double` удовлетворяли стандарту IEEE 754, но обычно удовлетворяют.

На практике я бы посоветовал относиться с осторожностью ко всему написанному выше. У компиляторов есть хитрые опции, которые в целях повышения производительности отключают строгое соответствие стандартам в вопросах арифметики с плавающей точкой. Например, [/fp:fast](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) в Visual Studio или [-ffast-math](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) в GCC. Если такие опции используются, нужно тщательно изучать документацию — не ломают ли оптимизации квадратные корни каким-нибудь изощрённым и неочевидным способом.

Comment: Очень хороший, исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Вот тут утверждение сильнее чем оно есть на самом деле: "Если произведение f * f". `(2^24)^2` - точно представимо.